# Plot Voronoi diagram with only three points using R and tripack-package

Tags: r

I try to plot a Voronoi diagram of three points:

```
library(tripack)
x<-c(1.7,-2.2,0.5)
y<-c(-0.6,-0.2,0.8)
v<-voronoi.mosaic(x,y)
plot(v)
```

However, it just shows an empty plot.

```
print(v)
```

gives:

```
voronoi mosaic:
nodes: (x,y): neighbours (<0: dummy node)
1: (-0.3238956,-1.120482): -1 -2 -3 
dummy nodes: (x,y)
1: (-0.3238956,-1.120482)
2: (-0.3238956,-1.120482)
3: (-0.3238956,-1.120482)
```

Is this a bug? Does this makes sense? In my understanding it should be perfectly fine to build a Voronoi diagram from three points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that could be considered a bug, since [the definition of Voronoi regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram#Formal_definition) makes good sense for sets with as few as two generator points.

The **deldir** package (which also implements Delauney triangulation and Dirichlet (Voronoi) tesselation) *does* correctly handle sets with three (and for that matter as few as two) generator points.

```
library(deldir)
x <- c(1.7,-2.2,0.5)
y <- c(-0.6,-0.2,0.8)

par(mfcol=c(1,2))
plot(deldir(x, y), asp=1)
plot(deldir(x[1:2], y[1:2]), asp=1)
```

[image]